# JSON field postgress like

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql, orm

Is it possible to filter data in json field using not equal but like operator? Models:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.db import models


class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    data = JSONField()
```

where data row:

```
{"breed": "labrador0", "owner": {"name": "Bob0", "other_pets": [{"name": "Fishy"}]}}
```

Then i use `Dog.objects.filter(data__breed='labrador0')` i receive data, but if i want to receive all row where data.breed like 'labrador%' - i dont know how to do it.

I try `Dog.objects.filter(data__breed__contains='labrador')` - no results.

In psql i can use `select * FROM polls_dog WHERE polls_dog.data ->> 'breed' like 'labrador4%';` is where are a way to do it throught orm?

Comment: Please check the spelling of your title: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :-

```
Dog.objects.filter(data__breed__startswith='labrador')
```

[This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/) may be helpful for you.